# Bootstrap table-responsive on tablet

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap's table-responsive to create a simple responsive table for my layout. However this class only works on mobile. Is there a way I can make it work on tablet as well?

```
<div class="histlog col-md-12">
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="hist1">One</th>
                <th class="hist2">Two</th>
                <th class="hist3">Three</th>
                <th class="hist4">Four</th>
                <th class="hist5">Five</th>
                <th class="hist6">Siz</th>
                <th class="hist7">Seven</th>
                <th>&nbsp;</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>6</td>
                <td>7</td>
                <td>8</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Here is the code. it is just a simple table layout.
And this is how it looks on mobile, my cells got smaller. Even when i adjusted the widths on my css, it wont respond to it.

[image]

Comment: code sample may help, if you have any...

Comment: @Urielzen I have updated my question with some more details.

Comment: @LajosArpad sorry what do you mean by mobile-responsive? currently my page is responsive and table-responsive looks perfect on mobile. i am only having trouble trying to adjust it for my table view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to consider using the `!important` rule in your CSS for your widths if you want to force the table to maintain the columns displayed as you anticipate.

Or you can use `white-space: nowrap;` like the example below to force the columns to not insert break lines that otherwise would happen first before your table starts behaving in a responsive manner. In other words, you are forcing the table to become responsive before trying to move text to a second line.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<style>
    td {
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
</style>
<div class="histlog col-md-12">
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="hist1">One</th>
                <th class="hist2">Two</th>
                <th class="hist3">Three</th>
                <th class="hist4">Four</th>
                <th class="hist5">Five</th>
                <th class="hist6">Siz</th>
                <th class="hist7">Seven</th>
                <th>&nbsp;</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1asdfasdf</td>
                <td>2asdfasdfasdf</td>
                <td>3asdfasdfasdf</td>
                <td>4asdfasd</td>
                <td>5asdfasddf asdf as</td>
                <td>6wer wer we </td>
                <td>7asdf asdfwe </td>
                <td>8sdfds f sd</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```